# full text multiple string search

Tags: mysql, wildcard

For a given tags column (id: 167) that is equal to "Hair Cut and Color",

trying to figure out why the following SQL statement outputs 0:

```
SELECT MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('+hair* +cut*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance FROM listings WHERE id = 167
```

Whereas the given SQL below returns 1:

```
SELECT MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('+hair* +cut' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance FROM listings WHERE id = 167
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL full-text search will ignore words that are 3 characters or less, unless you have changed the minimum length variable. I think that's the source of the problem here. The wildcard is looking for cut as a root in words that are 4 characters long or longer, and not finding any. Whereas when you have cut in the search without the wildcard, it's simply ignored as too short.

To look for shorter words, you can change the innodb_ft_min_token_size variable (if using innodb) or the ft_min_word_len variable (if using myisam) in an option file.

See more here: [Fine Tuning MySQL Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)

Comment: Even though the example words used, are not **Stop Words**, it is also helpful to note that MySQL looks at these as well and ignores them: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html